# spring-social-facebook fixes (maven)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-social-facebook

I am currently using spring-social-facebook it works quite fine except a few things which aren't up to date.

I tried to fix it on my own (forked from github and fixed it) 
Now after i build the project

[image]

[image]

I added those three jars to my pom.xml but none of the classes got recognized.

Added those three like this in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/spring-social-facebook-3.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

And from maven the jars are loaded but in java i cant use Objects from this jar's

Comment: "I added those three jars to my pom.xml" => _Show it!_ "None of the classes got recognized" => _What exactly does that mean? Please post the error if you get any._

Comment: edited above :)